# My views are not rendering

Tags: angularjs

i'm new to angularjs,my problem is that i cannot render the views by using routes,here is my folder structure,i can't figure what is the problem with my code

- index.html
- three.html
- two.html

  ```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html lang="en">
          <head>
              <title>AngularJS Routes example</title>
              <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
              <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
          </head>

          <body ng-app="sampleApp">

          <a href="#/two">Route 2</a><br/>
          <a href="#/three">Route 3</a><br/>

          <div ng-view></div>


          <script>
              var app = angular.module("sampleApp", ['ngRoute']);

              app.config(['$routeProvider',
                  function($routeProvider) {
                      $routeProvider.
                          when('/three', {
                              templateUrl: 'three.html',
                              controller: 'RouteController'
                          }).
                          when('/two', {
                              templateUrl: 'two.html',
                              controller: 'RouteController'
                          }).
                          otherwise({
                              redirectTo: '/'
                          });
                  }]);

              app.controller("RouteController", function($scope) {

              })
          </script>
          </body>
  ```

Comment: You should develop the question or it will most likely be downvoted.

Comment: `module` variable is not defined. You want `app.controller(...)`.

Comment: changed to app.controller() still nothing

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/9IjiKRsvCysWbMlcGty4?p=preview

Comment: @dfsq its still not working i get the following error     XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/johnny/Desktop/New%20folder/two.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
angular.min.js:83 Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///C:/Users/johnny/Desktop/New%20folder/two.html'.

Comment: You need to run local webserver, you will not be able to use file://  protocol.